# Trying to port my interactive ncurses game of life from C to python

Tags: python, c, curses, conways-game-of-life

I have a single out of range bug when trying to iterate over the grid to count neighbor cells. It's almost done, but I've spent a couple hours on this one bug already. I'm determined to deal with the rest of them if any after this. lol. I've never asked for help on stack exchange before, so be sure that I wouldn't if not having tried everything and being thoroughly frustrated. Go easy on me. lol

The C code works. If anybody wants the declarations for the C implementation I would be happy to post them.

To reproduce the bug, fire it up with python3 in a *nix terminal, and press "enter". You might do it on windows, but I guess you need to do some work with pdcurses.

It seems possible now that the C code has undetected errors despite working, and throwing no compiler warnings.

When iterating over the 2D array, the code is supposed to work by adding +1 to the grid(grid.cell) index, so as not to go out of bounds when counting cells just out of the screen. From the rudimentary debug output I added to grid.neighbor_count, I can see that it gets all the way to the far side of the screen on the x axis before it throws an error, so going negative on the y axis seems to work as expected. I've seen several other ways to do this, but this seems the most elegant to me, and it works in C already.

### Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./life.py", line 118, in <module>
    main()
  File "./life.py", line 100, in main
    grid.draw_next(term)
  File "./life.py", line 49, in draw_next
    j = self.neighbor_count(y,x)
  File "./life.py", line 38, in neighbor_count
    count += self.cell[i+1][j+1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

### Python

```
from blessed import Terminal
#import signal
import sys


def echo(text):
    print(text, end='', flush=True)

class Grid(object):
    def __init__(self, y, x):
        self.cell = [([0] * x) for i in range(y)]

    def resize(self, y, x):
        pass

    def width(self, x=0):
        if not x: return len(self.cell[0][:])

    def height(self, y=0):
        if not y: return len(self.cell[:][:])

    def toggle_cell(self, y, x):
        i = self.cell[y][x]
        if i:
            self.cell[y][x] = 0
            return 0
        else:
            self.cell[y][x] = 1
            return 1

    def neighbor_count(self, y, x):
        count = 0
        for i in range(y-1,y+2):
            for j in range(x-1,x+2):
# debug         sys.stderr.write('i: {0} j: {1} '.format(i, j))
# debug         sys.stderr.write('y: {0} x: {1}\n'.format(y, x))
                count += self.cell[i+1][j+1]
        return count - self.cell[y][x]


class Grid(Grid):
    lifeform = '+'

    def draw_next(self, term):
        new = [([0] * (term.width)) for i in range(term.height)]
        for y in range(term.height):
            for x in range(term.width):
                j = self.neighbor_count(y,x)
                if j == 2:
                    new[y+1][x+1] = self.cell[y+1][x+1]
                elif j == 3:
                    new[y+1][x+1] = 1;
                    with term.location(x=x, y=y):
                        echo(self.lifeform)
                else:
                    new[y+1][x+1] = 0
                    with term.location(x=x, y=y):
                        echo(' ')
        self.cell = new

def main():
    """Program entry point."""
    term = Terminal()
    y_pos,x_pos = 0,0

    def draw(y, x, string):
        with term.location(y=y, x=x):
            echo(string)
    def move(y, x):
        echo(term.move(y, x))

    grid = Grid(term.height, term.width)
    with term.cbreak(), term.fullscreen():
        inp, inp0 = '',''
        echo(term.clear)
        while inp0 not in ('q', 'Q', 'KEY_ESCAPE'):
            inp0 = term.inkey() # timeout=1
            inp = repr(inp0)
            if not inp:
                # timeout
                break
            elif inp0 == ' ':
                if grid.toggle_cell(y_pos, x_pos):
                    draw(y_pos, x_pos, grid.lifeform)
                else: draw(y_pos, x_pos, ' ')
            elif inp == 'KEY_UP' and y_pos > 0:
                y_pos -= 1
                move(y_pos, x_pos)
            elif inp == 'KEY_DOWN' and y_pos < term.height-1:
                y_pos += 1
                move(y_pos, x_pos)
            elif inp == 'KEY_RIGHT' and x_pos < term.width-1:
                x_pos += 1
                move(y_pos, x_pos)
            elif inp == 'KEY_LEFT' and x_pos > 0:
                x_pos -= 1
                move(y_pos, x_pos)
            elif inp == 'KEY_ENTER':
                grid.draw_next(term)
            # everything down here was for debugging info
            elif inp0 == 'x':
                draw(y_pos, x_pos, x_pos)
            elif inp0 == 'y':
                draw(y_pos, x_pos, y_pos)
            elif inp0 == 'w':
                draw(y_pos, x_pos, grid.width())
            elif inp0 == 'h':
                draw(y_pos, x_pos, grid.height())
            elif inp0 == 'W':
                draw(y_pos, x_pos, term.width)
            elif inp0 == 'H':
                draw(y_pos, x_pos, term.height)
            elif inp0 == 'g':
                draw(y_pos, x_pos, term.get_location())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### C

```
#include"life.h"

int main(){
    init_win();
    game_on = 1; //init_game();
    while(game_on){
        //get_color();
        input();
        wrefresh(stdscr);
    }
    quit();
    return 0;
}

void init_win(){
    initscr();
    nodelay(stdscr,TRUE);  // don't block for input, getch()
    raw();
    cbreak();           // take input chars one at a time, no wait for \n
    noecho();           // don't print input directly
    curs_set(2);
    keypad(stdscr,TRUE);   // enable keyboard mapping
}

void init_game(){
    want_color = 1;

    srand(time(NULL));

    if (has_colors() && want_color) { start_color(); }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        init_pair(i, color_table[i], COLOR_BLACK);

    game_on = 1;
}

void input(){
    switch(getch()){
        case 'q':
            nodelay(stdscr,FALSE);
            mvprintw(0,0,"Really quit? [y/N]");
            refresh();
            if(getch()=='y'){
                game_on = 0;
            }
            else{
                move(y_pos,x_pos);
                refresh();
                nodelay(stdscr,TRUE);
            }
        break;
        case 'c':
            clear_grid();
        break;
        case ' ':
            toggle_cell(y_pos,x_pos);
        break;
        case KEY_UP:
            if(y_pos > 0){
                y_pos--;
                move(y_pos,x_pos);
            }
        break;
        case KEY_DOWN:
            if(y_pos < LINES-1){
                y_pos++;
                move(y_pos,x_pos);
            }
        break;
        case KEY_LEFT:
            if(x_pos > 0){
                x_pos--;
                move(y_pos,x_pos);
            }
        break;
        case KEY_RIGHT:
            if(x_pos < COLS-1){
                x_pos++;
                move(y_pos,x_pos);
            }
        break;
        case 10: // 10 == newline
            // leaveok(stdscr,1);
            update_generation();
            move(y_pos,x_pos);
            //leaveok(stdscr,0);
        break;
    }
}

void clear_grid(){
    for (int y=0;y<1000;y++)
        for (int x=0;x<1000;x++)
            grid[y][x] = 0;
    erase();
}

void draw(int y,int x,char z){
    move(y,x);
    delch();
    insch(z);
}

void get_color(){
    chtype bold = (rand() % 2) ? A_BOLD : A_NORMAL;
    attrset(COLOR_PAIR(rand() % 8) | bold);
}

void toggle_cell(int y,int x){
    if (grid[y+1][x+1]==1){
        grid[y+1][x+1] = 0;
        draw(y,x,' ');
    } else {
        grid[y+1][x+1] = 1;
        draw(y,x,CELL);
    }
}

int neighbor_count(int y,int x){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=y-1;i<=y+1;i++){
        for(int j=x-1;j<=x+1;j++){
            count += grid[i+1][j+1];
        }
    }
    count -= grid[y+1][x+1];
    return(count);
}

void update_generation(){
    int new_grid[1000][1000];
    for (int y=0;y<LINES;y++)
        for (int x=0;x<COLS;x++)
            switch(neighbor_count(y,x)){
                case 2:
                    new_grid[y+1][x+1] = grid[y+1][x+1];
                break;
                case 3:
                    new_grid[y+1][x+1] = 1;
                    draw(y,x,CELL);
                break;
                default:
                    new_grid[y+1][x+1] = 0;
                    draw(y,x,' ');
                }
    for (int y=0;y<LINES;y++)
        for (int x=0;x<COLS;x++)
            grid[y+1][x+1] = new_grid[y+1][x+1];
}

void quit(){
    nocbreak();
    echo();
    endwin();
}
```

Comment: If you're at an edge, `x + 1` and `y + 1` will attempt to read after the end of the list (off the edge of the board)... I haven't written C in a LONG time, but I don't think it's explicitly an /error/ in C so much as just a bug in your program (if that makes any sense). But it *is* an error in Python.

Comment: Pretty sure that `grid = Grid(term.height, term.width)` needs to be `grid = Grid(term.height+2, term.width+2)`. Based on the `clear_grid` function, it seems that you solved the problem in C by making the `grid` array much bigger than necessary.

Comment: Wow. I knew it was simple. I guess trying to use different structure and libraries threw me off a bit.
I can make the array a little bigger on each side, and only count cells within the terminal size. I made the array bigger in C to very simply resize the terminal and not have to deal with memory allocation, so it was a complete accident that it worked out this way.
I really appreciate your guys` help. Glad I asked. lol